# Passing parameters with spaces

Tags: bash

Why is the output of `test foo bar` only `foo` instead of `foo bar`?

```
$ cat test
function f
{
    local args=$1

    echo $args
}
f "$@"

$ bash test foo bar
foo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass the command-line parameters as a single argument to your function you can join them together using `"$*"` (instead of `$@`):

```
f "$*"
```

The first character of variable `IFS` is used as the "glue" between each parameter, the default is a single space.

Comment: The right hand side of assignments is not expanded, so the quotes around $1 are not necessary

Comment: The problem is not how I pass the arguments to the script but how I fail to pass all incoming arguments as one parameter to f. I reason that f gets a single parameter: "foo bar".

Comment: @cebewee; yes, you are right, I was probably editing my reply as you posted your comment.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom: then use `f "$*"` instead (the " are critical).  See my edit.

Comment: cdarke: OK, thanks. The second part of your reply is the answer to my question (you may consider removing the first part).

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom: glad to help, sorry about the misunderstanding.  Answer edited as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

because bar is $2. if you want both foo and bar to be passed as a single param, you have to call it like this:

bash test "foo bar"

Comment: No, that's not my problem. I pass the two command line arguments as *one* parameter ("$@") to f, but still it only seems to receive the first.

Comment: This is exactly the difference between `"$@"` and `"$*"`